# Blender to unity animation issues

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

I have a model with animations in blender, which I then put into my unity file as a FBX file.
[image]

[image]

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK Bendy bones aren't supported outside of Blender, you need to disable that.

Comment: You are using bending bones man, this just works on blender. Follow those tips
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUdefdwx-CM